# Show $X$ is reflexive iff $\iota_{X^{**}}=(\iota_X)^{**}$

Tags: functional-analysis, dual-spaces

> **Exercise 2.96 (The canonical inclusion)** Let $X$ be a normed vector space and let $\iota_X\colon X\to X^{**}$ be the canonical inclusion defined by (2.39).
>
> **(a)** Show that $(\iota_X)^*\iota_{X^*}=\operatorname{id}_{X^*}$ and determine the kernel of the projection $$P:=\iota_{X^*}(\iota_X)^*\colon X^{***}\to X^{***}.$$
>   **(b)** Assume $X$ is complete. Show that $X$ is reflexive if and only if $$\iota_{X^*}(\iota_X)^*=\operatorname{id}_{X^{***}}.$$
>   **(c) Lipton's Pullback** Let $Y\subset X$ be a closed subspace and let $j\colon Y\to X$ be the obvious inclusion. Then $\iota_X\diamond j=j^{**}\diamond\iota_{Y}\colon Y\to X^{**}$. This map is an isometric embedding of $Y$ into $X^{**}$ whose image is $$\iota_X\diamond j(Y)=j^{**}\diamond\iota_Y(Y)=\iota_X(X)\cap j^{**}(Y^{**})\subset X^{**}.$$
>   **(d)** Deduce from Lipton's Pullback that $Y$ is reflexive whenever $X$ is reflexive.
>
> **(e)** Show that $X$ is reflexive if and only if $\iota_{X^{**}}=(\iota_X)^{**}$.
>
> **Note** This exercise requires the notion of the dual operator, introduced in Definition 4.1 below.
>
> [(Image that replaced text.)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RLMZl.png)

---

I see to show that the identity $\iota_{X^{**}}=(\iota_X)^{**}$ implies that $X$ is reflexive. I have the other direction using only (b).  This is part (e) of a five part problems and I have to use parts (c), (d).

It only makes sense that I have to appeal to Linton's pullback using some kind of closed subspace but I cannot possibly think of one.  I'm guaranteed the trivial subspace but that's rather unhelpful. I tried assuming that $x\in X^{**}-\iota_X(X)$ and then applying Linton to $\langle x\rangle$ (the span of $x$) to get some kind of contradiction but that makes no sense. I'm very stuck here.

Comment: I think you will get more help from people, if you take the time to write out the question that you have, rather than asking people to look it up in a book.

Comment: I edited the problem but it is still closed. Must I start a new problem?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, if you edit a problem shortly after it was closed, there is a possibility that it will be reopened. Also, since you have included some remarks about what you've done and what you're still stuck on, I think that that may help to get the problem reopened.

Comment: Writing down concretely what is $(\iota_X)^*$ and the other maps in the case of $X=c_0$ and $\ell^1$ might help to see what's happening (you'll need Hahn-Banach to extend the bounded linear map $f(x)=\lim_n x_n$ on $c_0+\Bbb{C}$ to $\ell^\infty$)

Comment: I'm finding this surprisingly difficult. Is it supposed to be trivial? The dual of $c_0$ is $l_1$ so $\iota_{c_0}(s)$, $s\in {c_0}$ should send a sequence in $l_1$ to $C$. The only map I can think of which would do this is to take the some kind of infinite dot product of the two sequences.

Answer (score 1):

The missing direction can be done elementarily, without the other steps. Show that if $X$ is not reflexive that then $\iota_{X^{**}}$ and $\iota_X^{**}$ must differ, hence if they are the same then $X$ has no choice but to be reflexive.

To that end let $f\in \iota_X(X)^\perp\subset X^{***}$ (by Hahn Banach this space is not zero if $X$ is not reflexive) and $x\in X^{**}$ with $f(x)\neq0$ (as a remark: $x\notin \iota_X(X)$).

Now
$$\iota_{X^{**}}(x)\,[f]=f(x)\neq0,\ \ \text{ while }\ \ \ \iota_X^{**}(x)\,[f]= x(\iota_X^*(f)) = x( v\in X\mapsto f(v) ) = x(0)=0.$$

It follows that $\iota_{X^{**}}\neq \iota_X^{**}$.

Comment: I don't see the existence of a nonzero $f$. Of course, if $\iota_X(X)$ is closed, H-B guarantees such an $f$. But what if the closure of $\iota_X(X)$ is $X^{**}$? Also, $\iota_X(X)$ is closed iff $X$ is Banach. Am I missing something?

Comment: $\iota_X$ is closed iff $X$ is Banach, I wasn't taking the non-Banach space case into account at all. There will probably be some elementary consideration that takes care of non-complete $X$, I'll see if I can think of it.

Comment: @ThomasShelby Looking at it more: $\iota_{X}^{**}(x)\,[f] = x(f\circ \iota_X)$ and $\iota_{X^{**}}(x)\,[f]= f(x)$. So if $x = \iota_X(y)$ one then has $\iota_{X}^{**}(\iota_X(y))\,[f]=\iota_X(y)\,[f\circ\iota_X]=f(\iota_X(y))$ and $\iota_{X^{**}}(\iota_X(y))\,[f]= f(\iota_X(y) )$. Hence the two maps agree on all points in $\iota_X(X)$, hence on $\overline{\iota_X(X)}$. This consideration cannot see if the original space is complete or not, the two maps would be equal if the completion of $X$ is reflexive.

Comment: In point (b) the exercise asks one to assume that $X$ is complete. Sometimes this means "from now on in all further sub-exercises assume that $X$ is complete". This is not so clear, but the consideration in my previous comment makes me think that the statement needs completeness of $X$.